# Django conditional queries: How can I avoid this?

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements

I have multiple conditional queries based on whether a variable is set or not and the value of 'doc_type'. But I think it looks ugly and I'm repeating code.
Is there a clearer way to get this done?

```
if status is not None:
    if doc_type == 4:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(Q(type=4) | Q(type=5) | Q(status=status))
    else:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(type=doc_type, status=status)
else:
    if doc_type == 4:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(Q(type=4) | Q(type=5))
    else:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(type=doc_type)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure this is what you want?

```
    invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(Q(type=4) | Q(type=5) | Q(status=status))
```

This will return all invoices where `type=4` OR `type=5` OR `status=Status`.

I think you mean (type is 4 or 5) **AND** status=status? If so, you can do your Query as follows:

```
types = [doc_type]
if doc_type == 4:
    types.append(5)
invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(type__in=types)
if status is not None:
    invoices = invoices.filter(status=status)
```

You can use `Q()` objects if you prefer, but I think that chaining filters is easier to understand in this case.

Answer (score 4):

[`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#q-objects) can be combined using `|` or `&`.

Using [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_) (`|`) and [`operator.and_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.and_) (`&`) which works as functions instead of operator, the code can be expressed as:

```
import operator

op = operator.and_
q = Q(type=doc_type)  # This is always included.
if doc_type == 4:
    # When doc_type == 4, conditions are combine with `|`, otherwise `&`
    op = operator.or_
    q = Q(type=doc_type) | Q(type=5)

if status is not None:
    q = op(q, status=status)

invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

If one `status` is `OR` and another `status` is `AND`, remember `QuerySet` supports `|` and `&` as well:

```
qs = Invoice.objects.filter(doc_type__in=(doc_type, 5) if doc_type == 4 else (doc_type,))
if status is not None:
    if doc_type == 4:
        qs |= Invoice.objects.filter(status=status)
    else:
        qs = qs.filter(status=status)
```